# Shiva with four hands | explanation

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam

Can anyone explain below form of Lord Shiva:

[image]

I have few specific question:

1. What’s the name of this form.
2. Front two hands are showing some mudras.
3. What’s the object attached to His Trishul.
4. Meaning to Trishul.
5. What’s the significance of damru.
6. Why He has snake garland at neck and hands.
7. Near Trishul is it a ghatam(what it signifies).
8. Please add if I miss any details.